# How to use yahoo api key with yql rest query

Tags: api, authentication, yql

I am attempting to get stock data from the yahoo finance tables using this url:

[Get Yahoo Stocks](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20startDate%20%3D%20%222014-12-26%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%22202014-12-26%22%20and%20symbol%20in%20(%22YHOO%22))

I would like to include my api key to this url to raise my access limits. I have a consumer key and consumer secret from a registered yahoo application. For the life of me, I can't find instructions on how to implement either of these ids.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I got the same question. Have you got any answer to this question yet?